# Find the probability that the ball ends up in the slot in the middle

Tags: probability, combinations

**Precalculus textbook problem (self-study)**: Shown in the figure is a small version of a probability demonstration device. A small ball is dropped into the top of the maze and tumbles to the bottom. Each time the ball strikes an obstacle, there is a $50 \%$ chance that the ball will move to the left. Find the probability that the ball ends up in the slot in the middle.

[image]

**Textbook answer in back of book**: $\frac{C(4,2)}{16}$.

**My solution**: I did this by counting paths (50% tells me that every path is equally likely). Vertically there are four levels of obstacles. The first level has one obstacle, the second level two obstacles, the third level three obstacles, and the fourth level has four obstacles.

When the ball reaches an obstacle on a level there are two possibilities: go right or go left. So by counting there are a total of $2^4$ paths the ball can take. This is the size of the sample of paths.

To count the number of paths that lead to the middle slot I used my mind's eye and counted six.

To write something down on paper I thought of numbering/labeling the obstacles. From left to right, top to bottom:

1

2, 3

4, 5, 6

7, 8, 9, 10.

Then the six paths are 1248, 1258, 1259, 1369, 1358, and 1359; hence, the probability is 6/16.

But while this works it's brute force, and it doesn't seem to be the approach of the author of the solution.

**Question**: How did the author of the solution get $C(4,2)$? I mean what does the 4 and the 2 represent here?

Here is my guess so far of how the the author of the solution came up with the numerator in terms of a combination.

The chief observation is that any (every) path to the middle slot is a combination of two lefts and two rights.  The number of such combinations is $C(4,2)$.

Comment: See also [Pascal's Triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question: How did the author of the solution get C(4,2)? I mean what
> does the 4 and the 2 represent here?

This means choosing 2 out of 4. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination

So exactly as you said, choosing 2 to be turning left out of 4 possible turns. The rest are right turns.